# Can't get plot using the Evaluate function

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, broken-code

I am trying to plot a series of five curves using a `loglogplot` command and then labeling the curves with a value. This is the program I am trying to run.

```
aa={5 10^-1, 5 10^-2,5 10^-3, 5 10^-4, 5 10^-5}

n[k,a]=a k (3+6 k+4 k^2+2 a k^3+a^2 k^4)/((1+a k) (1+a^2 k^4+2 a k (2+3 k+2 k^2)))

lst=Table[n[k,a],{a,aa}]

LogLogPLot[
      {Evaluate[lst]},{k,0.1,100},
      PlotRange {{0.1,100},{0.001,1}},
      AxesOrigin {0.001,0.001},
      Epilog {Text["a=5 10^-1",{.005,0.3},{1,0}], 
      Text["a=5 10^-2",{0.5,0.25},{1,0}], 
      Text["a=5 10^-3",{1.0,0.25},{1,0}], 
      Text["a=5 10^-4",{3.0,0.25},{1,0}], 
      Text["a=5 10^-5",{7.0,0.3},{1,0}]}, 
      Gridlines Automatic, 
      Frame True, 
      Framelabel {"k","n"}, 
      ImageSize 600
]
```

No plots occur. I don't understand the error.

Comment: This code is a mess (in addition to not being formatted; please see [editing help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)).  Is this actually a copy from your Notebook?  First, Symbol names are case sensitive so `LogLogPLot` is not the same as `LogLogPlot`.  Second, all of the Options need to be Rules, e.g. `Frame -> True`.  Did the `->` part go missing when you copied the code?

Comment: Is there a specific error message? What does it say?

Comment: You should heed Mr.Wizard's advice. I only answered the question because I'm still learning Mathematica and I wanted to refine my skills.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple formatting errors consisting of missing `->`, incorrect capitalization and function definition. Take a look at [`LogLogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLogPlot.html) and [`Defining Functions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefiningFunctions.html).

I also used [`PlotLabels`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLabels.html) to automatically associate labels with individual curves as opposed to the more manual method of `Epilog`.

```
aa = {5*^-1, 5*^-2, 5*^-3, 5*^-4, 5*^-5};

n[k_, a_] := a k (3 + 6 k + 4 k^2 + 2 a k^3 + 
             a^2 k^4)/((1 + a k) (1 + a^2 k^4 + 2 a k (2 + 3 k + 2 k^2))) 

LogLogPlot[Evaluate[
  Table[n[k, aa[[a]]], {a, 1, 5}]], {k, 0.1, 100}, 
  AxesOrigin->{1, 0.1},AxesLabel->{"k", "n"}, 
  GridLines->Automatic, Frame->True, ImageSize->600, 
  PlotLabels -> Placed[Text["a = " <> ToString[#]] & /@ N[aa], Left]
   (*Epilog ->{
     Text["a=5 10^-1",{-2,-1}],
     Text["a=5 10^-2",{-2,-3}],
     Text["a=5 10^-3",{-2,-5}],
     Text["a=5 10^-4",{-2,-7}],
     Text["a=5 10^-5",{-2,-9}]}*)
 ]
```

[image]